# Why does this XPath filter not work (maximum number)?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
<test>
   <child id="13680621263370126043"/>
   <child id="13680621263370124329"/>
</test>
```

Code:

```
doc.SelectNodes(@"/test/child[@Id=13680621263370126043]");
```

the returned list has both child nodes in it, what gives?

Comment: Because xml is case sensitive.  `Id` is not the same as `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 /test/child[@Id=13680621263370126043]
```

to

```
 /test/child[@id='13680621263370126043']
```

because

1. XML is case-sensitive.
2. The value being tested is too long to be tested as a number.

---

### Note on maximum numbers in XPath

[XPath uses double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 value](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers) for numbers, which has [15-17 signicant decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).  The `@id` attribute here has 20 digits and therefore must be tested as a string, not as a number.

Comment: Ah there we go, fat fingered the case thing on my example, but the second issue was it, Thanks!

Finally found this in the docs:

All elements and attributes are strings, but are automatically cast as integer values for numeric comparisons. Literal numeric values are cast to long or double types during comparison operations, as shown in the following table.

Comment: Nice for the explanation on why it isn't working as a number

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems:

1. It is **case sensitive**. It should be `id` and not `Id`.
2. Wrap the value with `''`

So:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("data.xml");
var result = doc.SelectNodes(@"//test/child[@id='13680621263370126043']");

// result contains 1 item
```